# Get A⊕(B+1) from A⊕B

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-algebra

I have numbers A,B,C.D.

(⊕ is XOR)

C = A⊕B

D = A⊕(B+1)

Is there any way to get D from C, when I do not know A and B? How?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What does ⊕ mean?

Comment: It means XORing bit by bit, edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. For example, suppose $A=B=0$. Then $C=0\oplus 0=0$, while $D=0 \oplus 1=1$. But if $A=B=1$, then we still have $C=0$, but now $D=1 \oplus 10=11$. Since one value of $C$ can correspond to two different values of $D$, $D$ cannot be deduced from $C$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks! Are two different values the maximum I can get? Can I get three(or more) different values of D for one C?

Comment: @TomášŠíma: Have you tried checking any examples at all?

Comment: That was stupid comment, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris explains, you cannot find $D$ exactly.

However, you *can* narrow down the *possible* values for $D$ considerably, which can be important in some contexts (such as cryptography).

$B+1$ always differs from $B$ in that a number of *least significant* bits have been flipped. No bit that is flipped is to the left of any bit that is preserved. This description carries over when you xor with the unknown $A$. So you *can* say that $D$ must be $C\oplus(2^n-1)$ for some $n\ge 1$.

(It is also easy to see that each of these values is in fact a *possible* value for $D$, given appropriate choice of $A$, no matter what $C$ is).

Comment: I solve this in relation to cryptography. In my example n<=8, so the cipher can be bruteforced easily. Thanks a lot!